# How to run SQL queries on VS 2019 using c++?

Tags: c++, sql, database, visual-studio

I have sucessfully connected to a SQL database that I created, using an option provided by Visual studio 2019.
[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4JFU.jpg).

As you can see from the picture, I also created a Query which retrieves tables from the database. Now, I would like to use this query in an command line application which I am creating using C++.

The App will store member details such as username and password.

Now I would like to make a LINK between the app and the database. Whenever a user types a username and a password, it should open the database and save that information (very simple). However, I just don't have a clue on how to make that LINK.

I also created a member class. How do I connect to my database and save all that information that a user provides?

Thank You

Comment: There are many possible ways to access a database with visual studio. I use sqlite from the Qt framework in c++ in visual studio.

Comment: I do not want to use sqlite. I am using SQL. And just want to know what piece of code i need to write so i can link my database to my application

Comment: My point is you will have to explain what you are doing before anyone can give you help. There are many ways to do this in native `c++` and managed  with the .NET framework or dozens of third party solutions to connect to dozens of different SQL databases.

Comment: SQL is a language, not database software. What database software is it? SQLite would make this very easy. You still use SQL to talk to it.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few different ways to do this.

#### MFC Classes

If you're using MFC in the rest of your application, you might want to use the database classes Microsoft includes in MFC.

- The first of these would be the CDatabase class. With it, the basic (perhaps oversimplified) idea is that you create a `CDatabase` object, then call its `Open` or `OpenEx` to open a connection to the database, probably call `BindParameters` to bind any parameters you need, and finally call `ExecuteSql` to do the query. It also has classes for things like storing and display the results of a query. It uses ODBC, which means you need to set up the database as an ODBC data source before you can use it this way.
- MFC also has a `CDaoDatabase` class to work with a database via DAO instead of via ODBC. Otherwise generally similar.
- MFC also has some OLE DB classes. Again, roughly similar to CDatabase, but for OLE DB sources. These can get a little confusing though--some of the classes that sound like they'd be related really aren't. For example, `COleDataSource` is actually the source of data in an OLE Drag and Drop operation, not at least normally a source of data to feed to (for example) a `COleDBRecordView`.

#### Third Party Libraries

There are also a number of third party libraries for doing similar things.

- [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/), is closer to what it sounds like you may want. It gives a fairly simple way to generate and execute a query (whereas MFC is really an application framework that tends to assume that to use any of it, your whole application should be written *its* way.
- [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/home.htm) is fairly similar to SOCI. Its main claim to fame is tighter integration with the standard collection/iterator/algorithm classes (or at least working more like them).
- [SQLAPPI++](https://www.sqlapi.com/) seems to me a *little* more like the MFC approach, but I've never done anything with it beyond building a couple of its samples, so I hesitate to say a lot--I don't really know how well it works out in real use, but I know people who've used it and been happy with the results.

There are a *lot* of other libraries around as well though--those are just a few that occur to me immediately.